# Apache as a service on Windows, security issues?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, apache-http-server, windows-services

#### TL;DR

For Apache as a service on Windows: is granting a domain user used for running Apache as a service and granting them the privilege of **Act as part of the operating system** a security concern? [The Apache website recommends this.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#winsvc) If it is a security issue, what should I be doing instead?

---

I am setting up **Apache 2.4 64-bit** on **Windows Server 2008**.

So far I have downloaded an archive of Apache from the [apachehaus website](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx) and extracted it to my desired directory and then set up Apache as a service by running `httpd.exe -k install` as per the instructions on the [Apache website](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#winsvc).

Now I can see the Apache service from services.msc

[image: Apache service from services.msc]

Following on from the instructions on setting up Apache as a service from the Apache website it states the following:

> By default, all Apache services are registered to run as the system
>   user (the LocalSystem account). The LocalSystem account has no
>   privileges to your network via any Windows-secured mechanism,
>   including the file system, named pipes, DCOM, or secure RPC. It has,
>   however, wide privileges locally.

Then it states, as a warning:

> Never grant any network privileges to the LocalSystem account! If you
>   need Apache to be able to access network resources, create a separate
>   account for Apache as noted below.

It then states that you should perform the following steps:

> It is recommended that users create a separate account for running Apache service(s). If you have to access network resources via Apache, this is required.
>
> 1. Create a normal domain user account, and be sure to memorize its password.
> 2. Grant the newly-created user a privilege of Log on as a service and Act as part of the operating system. On Windows NT 4.0 these
>      privileges are granted via User Manager for Domains, but on Windows
>      2000 and XP you probably want to use Group Policy for propagating
>      these settings. You can also manually set these via the Local Security
>      Policy MMC snap-in.
> 3. Confirm that the created account is a member of the Users group.
> 4. Grant the account read and execute (RX) rights to all document and script folders (htdocs and cgi-bin for example).
> 5. Grant the account change (RWXD) rights to the Apache logs directory.
> 6. Grant the account read and execute (RX) rights to the httpd.exe binary executable.

and it goes on ... after googling up on some of the aforementioned steps I came across some [forum posts](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=30721) that raised some security concerns regarding step 2:

**2. Grant the newly-created user a privilege of Log on as a service and *Act as part of the operating system.***

So, could anyone confirm if granting a domain user utilised for running Apache as a service and granting them the privilege of **Act as part of the operating system** is a security concern? Is it required? Is there a better approach to take here?

The aforementioned security concerns I found on the forums linked to the following Microsoft website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/dn221957 which states:

> The Act as part of the operating system policy setting determines whether a process can assume the identity of any user and thereby gain access to the resources that the user is authorised to access.

Comment: Why do you want to use a domain user? I also see no need for the “Act as part of the operating system” privilege. I’d create a dedicated (local, if possible) user account for the service.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for your comment. My question is simply explaining the instructions from the Apache website. I didn't decide I wanted to use a domain user, the apache website states `Create a normal domain user account` see the link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#winsvc. Re: creating a dedicated local user - I'm guessing a local user account would not be the same as the `LocalSystem` account? Apologies for my ignorance here, this isn't really my area of expertise!

Comment: There is a separate "local user and groups" dialog (`lusrmgr.msc`) available in windows which would list things like the local `Administrator` group and the local `Administrator` account.